# Returning value form function using POM in Protractor

Tags: protractor

I am working on POM for calculator website. However i am blocked while returning value from function to my main spec file to expect.

below is the files
**PageObjectFile**

```
var calc_new = function(){
let firstField= element(by.model('first'));
let secondField= element(by.model('second'));
let option=element.all(by.tagName('option'));
let tbody = element(by.tagName('tbody'));
let go = element(by.id('gobutton'));
// let firstField= element(by.model('first'));

this.firstNumber=function(first){
    firstField.sendKeys(first);
};
this.secondNumber=function(second){
    secondField.sendKeys(second);
};

this.operatorSelection=function(oprt){
    option.each(function(opt){
        opt.getText().then(function(oprc){
            if(oprc==oprt){
                console.log('##OPRC: '+oprc);
                opt.click();
                }
            });  
    }); 

};
this.clickGo= function(){
    go.click();
};

this.getResult= function(){
    browser.sleep(5000);
        tbody.all(by.tagName('tr')).each(function(row){
            row.all(by.tagName('td')).last().getText().then(function(Result){
                console.log('Result is '+ Result);
                return Result;
            });
        //How can i return this Result to spec file TestNew.js
        });
    }
};module.exports = new calc_new();
```

SpecFile.js

```
        var calc= require('../PageElements/calc_new');
describe('Its a test Suite', function(){
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    it('Calculation Operations',function(){
    browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo');
    calc.firstNumber('100');
    calc.secondNumber('30');
    calc.operatorSelection('*');
    calc.clickGo();
    //Want to expect here after returning value from getResult()
    expect(calc.getResult()).toEquals(3000);
}); });
```

**Please suggest me any way to solve this**

====
Here Every time i am getting output 
**Expected undefined to equal '3000'**

Please help me out to solve this issue.

Comment: do you want to return on a specific table cell value?

Comment: why you don't use ES6 syntax with class? It would much more easier. Also, I don't understand what exactly value do you want to get, because you use `each()`. So, it's going be array of Results. Also do you use Control Flow or not? I will certainly recommend not use it.

Comment: Hi Thank you for quick reply. In this script i want to return a single value from this piece of code row.all(by.tagName('td')).last().getText().then(function(Result){
                console.log('Result is '+ Result);
            });

Comment: Please see the original(top) code for better understandnig

Comment: Are you trying to get the value in the last cell of the first row? If not then which value are you expecting

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the `getResult` function has `return` statement.

1) Approach of directly return the text of 3rd td of 1st row.

```
this.getResult= function(){

    browser.sleep(5000);

    // the latest calculate result always at the 1rd row and the 3rd cell
    return tbody.element(by.css('tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(3)')).getText();
};
```

2) Approach of using `ElementFinderArray.filter`

```
this.getResult= function(){

    browser.sleep(5000);

    return tbody.element(by.css('tr')).filter((row, index)=>{
        // the latest calculate result always at the 1rd row and the 3rd cell
        if(index === 0) {
            return row.all(by.css('td')).last();
        }
    }).then((td)={
        return td.getText();
    })
};
```

3) Approach of using `ElementFinderArray.getText()`

```
this.getResult= function(){

    browser.sleep(5000);

    return tbody.element(by.css(' > td'))
        .getText()
        .then((txts)=>{
            // the latest calculate result always at the 1rd row and the 3rd cell
            return txts && txts[2];
        })
};
```

Comment: Hi i did this this is whole the function  same as in initial post                                         this.getResult= function(){
    browser.sleep(5000);
        tbody.all(by.tagName('tr')).each(function(row){
            row.all(by.tagName('td')).last().getText().then(function(Result){
                console.log('Result is '+ Result);
                return Result;
            });
        //How can i return this Result to spec file TestNew.js
        });
    }

Comment: you only have a `return` in nested function, not on the top of the `getResult()`. And `element.all().each()` can only return a promise with null value.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I tried by resolving the promise before returning it to my spec file using below code :

```
this.getResult = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) { 
    // Resolve the promise before returning to main spec
    browser.sleep(5000);
    tbody.all(by.tagName('tr')).each(function(row) {
      row.all(by.tagName('td')).last().getText().then(function(Result) {
        // value = Result;
        console.log('Result is ' + Result);
        resolve(Result);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Please advice me is it a good approach?
Or is there any other way to solve my issue.

Comment: Above code can resolve your issue, but more complex.

Comment: @yong, could you please suggest the other way to solve this?

Comment: If you definitely know  I want to get text on the 3rd cell of the first row, you can directly locate that cell, no need to use `each()` and `all().last()` to make your code looks complex.  `by.css('tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(3)')` can directly locate that cell as the approach 1) in my answer.